# Catching the clicks on an HTML5-canvas

Tags: html, coffeescript

I'd like to catch the **clicks** on my **HTML5-canvas**.

My **object**:

```
mouse =
  position:
    x: 0
    y: 0
    set: (event) ->
      boundaries = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
      this.position.x = event.clientX - boundaries.left
      this.position.y = event.clientY - boundaries.top
```

My **event listener**:

```
window.addEventListener 'click', (event) ->
  event.preventDefault()
  mouse.position.set event
  console.log "#{mouse.position.x} - #{mouse.position.y}"
```

The **error message**:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.position.x = event.clientX - boundaries.left')
```

What's wrong with this piece of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have the Answer:

```
mouse =
  position:
    x: 0
    y: 0
    set: (event) ->
      boundaries = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
      mouse.position.x = event.clientX - boundaries.left
      mouse.position.y = event.clientY - boundaries.top
```

You should not use the this keyword. Better use the proper object name:

- **mouse**.position.x
- **mouse**.position.y

and:

```
canvas.addEventListener 'click', (event) ->
  event.preventDefault()
  mouse.position.set event
  console.log "#{mouse.position.x} - #{mouse.position.y}"
```

yeah, it works.

Comment: This can also be solved using scope binding. Simply replace the `->` with `=>` for the `set` function. This will pass the `this` context from the object to the function, rather than letting it be set by the function to the event target. Also +1 for answering your question after finding a solution rather than leaving it open